# Navigate after successful login failed

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic 2 and I want to create a navigate when the login is successful so I used this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Page1} from '../page1/page1';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class Login {
  private nav:NavController = null;    
    static get parameters() 
    {
        return [[Http]], [[NavController]];
    }

    constructor(public http:Http, nav: NavController)  
    {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    login(credentials) 
    {     
            this.http.post(url, UserLogin)
          .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((response) => 
            {
                console.log("Welkom");
                this.nav.setRoot(Page1);
                this.nav.popToRoot();
            });   
    }
}
```

It login worked without nav but now I added NavControllers to parameter because otherwhise I got an error

> this.nav is undefined

But now I got error:

> this.http.post is not a function

Fault is here I guess:

```
 return [[Http]], [[NavController]];
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

I want to set Page1 as Rootpage and then I want to navigate to it.

Is there also a possibility to print some text to user like: "wrong password" using error or something?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing two ways of importing.

`static get Parameters` is not required

Use constructor based injection without get parameters:

> constructor(public http:Http, public nav: NavController)   { }

By setting public/private access specifiers you dont have to do `this.nav=nav;`

Comment: Ok.. The first one is an older way.. will remove it from my answer